# Does a polynomial-time algorithm for factoring product of two primes imply a polynomial-time algorithm for factoring in general?

Tags: ds.algorithms, conditional-results, comp-number-theory

Is it known if the existence of a polynomial-time algorithm for the promise problem of factoring of numbers with two prime factors implies that factoring in general has a polynomial-time algorithm?

Comment: in general no reason to believe that.